# Updating Price on Specific Product

Tags: magento

In Magento(1.8), I have many products, I only want to update the price on  products with attributes: Tires, and Wheels by 12 % and 15 %. I tried using the free extension called Bulk Update All Product Prices(savethemage extension) but that will update all product.Any idea on how to do it in mysql?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Promotions > Catalog Price Rules > Add New Rule > and create new rule by selecting required attribute

[image]

go through following links for complete information : http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-catalog-price-rules/

Comment: I updated my question.I want to update price on specific products with the following attributes: wheels and tires.How would you do it?

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking.I will try this on my local server.I will accept this answer once successful

Comment: I think the answer you provided just allow me to decrease the price, not to increase

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga did you found solution. if so Please accept the answer